# Can I use Rails' :notice to a non-rails page (without using AJAX)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form that I give to my customers to put on THEIR website.  The form allows one of THEIR customers to request an appointment through my scheduling software.

My scheduling software has a controller action that creates the customer record and saves the work request to MY customer's environment (inside my software).

When the record is saved, I would like to pop and alert or do a flash[:success]-esque notice to THEIR customer that the requested was successfully submitted.

I DO NOT WANT TO USE AJAX FOR THIS.

Is there a way to put a  on MY customer's page and have the Rails redirect_to :back, :notice => "Request submitted successfully" function properly?

I can't give my customer a form.html.erb file or snippet.  It needs to be dumb, pure, basic HTML that will work under any webpage.  Lot's of restrictions for this.

I understand how I might do this with AJAX - I want to know if there is a way to do it without AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

I did NOT find any solution to using :notice the way that I want, but one work-around I did find was to put a hidden field in my form, manually set the callback URL, and pass that as the redirect like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="CALLBACK URL HERE">
```

In the controller after I submit my data I do:

```
redirect_to params[:redirect]
```

Which works a treat because you can put a nice landing page instead of just having a JavaScript alert saying "Success" or whatever